# how can I verify support IN AWS sign v4?

Tags: python-2.7, boto3

I am still using python27.

When I upgrade my boto installation, I got the following output:

```
$ pip install --upgrade boto3
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Collecting boto3
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3a/47/c7c92c453593a7b2a062bde3c5f714a4c5c12763f97b8b9c7a7480932bb1/boto3-1.9.167-py2.py3-none-any.whl (128kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 133kB 7.6MB/s 
Collecting s3transfer<0.3.0,>=0.2.0 (from boto3)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/16/8a/1fc3dba0c4923c2a76e1ff0d52b305c44606da63f718d14d3231e21c51b0/s3transfer-0.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 (from boto3)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/83/94/7179c3832a6d45b266ddb2aac329e101367fbdb11f425f13771d27f225bb/jmespath-0.9.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting botocore<1.13.0,>=1.12.167 (from boto3)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7b/00/8437c07663969bd219aab33299f17b9d0ecd82622f4e19f482483efbfc6d/botocore-1.12.167-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.5MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 5.5MB 5.6MB/s 
Collecting futures<4.0.0,>=2.2.0; python_version == "2.6" or python_version == "2.7" (from s3transfer<0.3.0,>=0.2.0->boto3)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2d/99/b2c4e9d5a30f6471e410a146232b4118e697fa3ffc06d6a65efde84debd0/futures-3.2.0-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting urllib3<1.26,>=1.20; python_version == "2.7" (from botocore<1.13.0,>=1.12.167->boto3)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e6/60/247f23a7121ae632d62811ba7f273d0e58972d75e58a94d329d51550a47d/urllib3-1.25.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1; python_version >= "2.7" (from botocore<1.13.0,>=1.12.167->boto3)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/17/c62faccbfbd163c7f57f3844689e3a78bae1f403648a6afb1d0866d87fbb/python_dateutil-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting docutils>=0.10 (from botocore<1.13.0,>=1.12.167->boto3)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/50/09/c53398e0005b11f7ffb27b7aa720c617aba53be4fb4f4f3f06b9b5c60f28/docutils-0.14-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1; python_version >= "2.7"->botocore<1.13.0,>=1.12.167->boto3)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: futures, urllib3, jmespath, six, python-dateutil, docutils, botocore, s3transfer, boto3
Successfully installed boto3-1.9.167 botocore-1.12.167 docutils-0.14 futures-3.2.0 jmespath-0.9.4 python-dateutil-2.8.0 s3transfer-0.2.1 six-1.12.0 urllib3-1.25.3
```

As you can see it installed boto3-1.9.167 botocore-1.12.167

So boto is of the latest version at the time of writing this question: https://github.com/boto/boto3/releases/tag/1.9.167

However I have trouble locating any release note. I just want to make sure AWS Sign v4 is supported and used in this version of boto.

How can I verify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The botocore [changelog](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.rst#1571) indicates that from version 1.7.51, all s3 requests use sigv4 by default. Since boto3 is based on botocore you can safely assume that sigv4 is supported by the versions you downloaded.